# C++ File Type changing,etc bank.in.out and cant just change it to bank.in

Tags: c++

I want to change its type to bank.in but its name changed but not the type how to do it, I created this bank.in by copying the out file

[image: Picture is here!]

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [rename](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/rename/). Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int result = rename("bank.in.out","bank.in");
    if(result == 0)
        std::cout << "successfully renamed the file" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

if you post the actual code we could look for a problem there.